# 301's not working with multisite

Tags: multisite, redirect

I had moved over my website a few months ago from a normal WordPress install to a Multisite install.

It's obvious that 301 redirection is something that needs to be set up with a new site after you create properly named pages and you want the old to redirect to the new, so I know I set this up. However, now I've used a couple different plugins over the last while, checked my `.htaccess` file, and no matter the plugin I use or the updates I do makes it work. I have a ton of 404 pages and of course it's not pretty.

Do I have to do something different with a multisite install for 301's to start working? Currently I'm using EPS Redirection plugin but checking any of my pages I'm redirecting causes me to go to a 404 page and not the redirected link.

Any help on this would be much appreciated. Been trying to figure out what is going on for a while now.

EDIT:

I've added my `.htaccess` code here:

```
# BEGIN iThemes Security - Do not modify or remove this line
# iThemes Security Config Details: 2
    # Enable HackRepair.com's blacklist feature - Security > Settings > Banned Users > Default Blacklist
    # Start HackRepair.com Blacklist
    RewriteEngine on
    # Start Abuse Agent Blocking
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} "^Mozilla.*Indy" [NC,OR]
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} "^Mozilla.*NEWT" [NC,OR]
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} "^$" [NC,OR]
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} "^Maxthon$" [NC,OR]
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} "^SeaMonkey$" [NC,OR]
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} "^Acunetix" [NC,OR]
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} "^binlar" [NC,OR]
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} "^BlackWidow" [NC,OR]
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} "^Bolt 0" [NC,OR]
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} "^BOT for JCE" [NC,OR]
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} "^Bot mailto\:craftbot@yahoo\.com" [NC,OR]
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} "^casper" [NC,OR]
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} "^checkprivacy" [NC,OR]
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} "^ChinaClaw" [NC,OR]
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} "^clshttp" [NC,OR]
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} "^cmsworldmap" [NC,OR]
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} "^comodo" [NC,OR]
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} "^Custo" [NC,OR]
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} "^Default Browser 0" [NC,OR]
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} "^diavol" [NC,OR]
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} "^DIIbot" [NC,OR]
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} "^DISCo" [NC,OR]
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} "^dotbot" [NC,OR]
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} "^Download Demon" [NC,OR]
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} "^eCatch" [NC,OR]
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} "^EirGrabber" [NC,OR]
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} "^EmailCollector" [NC,OR]
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} "^EmailSiphon" [NC,OR]
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} "^EmailWolf" [NC,OR]
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} "^Express WebPictures" [NC,OR]
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} "^extract" [NC,OR]
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} "^ExtractorPro" [NC,OR]
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} "^EyeNetIE" [NC,OR]
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} "^feedfinder" [NC,OR]
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} "^FHscan" [NC,OR]
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} "^FlashGet" [NC,OR]
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} "^flicky" [NC,OR]
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} "^g00g1e" [NC,OR]
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} "^GetRight" [NC,OR]
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} "^GetWeb\!" [NC,OR]
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} "^Go\!Zilla" [NC,OR]
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} "^Go\-Ahead\-Got\-It" [NC,OR]
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} "^grab" [NC,OR]
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} "^GrabNet" [NC,OR]
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} "^Grafula" [NC,OR]
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} "^harvest" [NC,OR]
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} "^HMView" [NC,OR]
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} "^ia_archiver" [NC,OR]
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} "^Image Stripper" [NC,OR]
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} "^Image Sucker" [NC,OR]
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} "^InterGET" [NC,OR]
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} "^Internet Ninja" [NC,OR]
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} "^InternetSeer\.com" [NC,OR]
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} "^jakarta" [NC,OR]
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} "^Java" [NC,OR]
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} "^JetCar" [NC,OR]
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} "^JOC Web Spider" [NC,OR]
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} "^kanagawa" [NC,OR]
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} "^kmccrew" [NC,OR]
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} "^larbin" [NC,OR]
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} "^LeechFTP" [NC,OR]
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} "^libwww" [NC,OR]
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} "^Mass Downloader" [NC,OR]
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} "^microsoft\.url" [NC,OR]
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} "^MIDown tool" [NC,OR]
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} "^miner" [NC,OR]
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} "^Mister PiX" [NC,OR]
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} "^MSFrontPage" [NC,OR]
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} "^Navroad" [NC,OR]
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} "^NearSite" [NC,OR]
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} "^Net Vampire" [NC,OR]
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} "^NetAnts" [NC,OR]
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} "^NetSpider" [NC,OR]
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} "^NetZIP" [NC,OR]
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} "^nutch" [NC,OR]
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} "^Octopus" [NC,OR]
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} "^Offline Explorer" [NC,OR]
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} "^Offline Navigator" [NC,OR]
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} "^PageGrabber" [NC,OR]
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} "^Papa Foto" [NC,OR]
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} "^pavuk" [NC,OR]
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} "^pcBrowser" [NC,OR]
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} "^PeoplePal" [NC,OR]
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} "^planetwork" [NC,OR]
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} "^psbot" [NC,OR]
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} "^purebot" [NC,OR]
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} "^pycurl" [NC,OR]
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} "^RealDownload" [NC,OR]
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} "^ReGet" [NC,OR]
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} "^Rippers 0" [NC,OR]
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} "^sitecheck\.internetseer\.com" [NC,OR]
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} "^SiteSnagger" [NC,OR]
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} "^skygrid" [NC,OR]
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} "^SmartDownload" [NC,OR]
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} "^sucker" [NC,OR]
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} "^SuperBot" [NC,OR]
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} "^SuperHTTP" [NC,OR]
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} "^Surfbot" [NC,OR]
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} "^tAkeOut" [NC,OR]
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} "^Teleport Pro" [NC,OR]
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} "^Toata dragostea mea pentru diavola" [NC,OR]
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} "^turnit" [NC,OR]
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} "^vikspider" [NC,OR]
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} "^VoidEYE" [NC,OR]
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} "^Web Image Collector" [NC,OR]
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} "^Web Sucker" [NC,OR]
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} "^WebAuto" [NC,OR]
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} "^WebBandit" [NC,OR]
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} "^WebCopier" [NC,OR]
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} "^WebFetch" [NC,OR]
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} "^WebGo IS" [NC,OR]
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} "^WebLeacher" [NC,OR]
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} "^WebReaper" [NC,OR]
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} "^WebSauger" [NC,OR]
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} "^Website eXtractor" [NC,OR]
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} "^Website Quester" [NC,OR]
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} "^WebStripper" [NC,OR]
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} "^WebWhacker" [NC,OR]
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} "^WebZIP" [NC,OR]
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} "^Wget" [NC,OR]
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} "^Widow" [NC,OR]
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} "^WPScan" [NC,OR]
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} "^WWW\-Mechanize" [NC,OR]
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} "^WWWOFFLE" [NC,OR]
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} "^Xaldon WebSpider" [NC,OR]
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} "^Zeus" [NC,OR]
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} "^zmeu" [NC,OR]
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} "360Spider" [NC,OR]
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} "AhrefsBot" [NC,OR]
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} "CazoodleBot" [NC,OR]
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} "discobot" [NC,OR]
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} "EasouSpider" [NC,OR]
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} "ecxi" [NC,OR]
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} "GT\:\:WWW" [NC,OR]
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} "heritrix" [NC,OR]
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} "HTTP\:\:Lite" [NC,OR]
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} "HTTrack" [NC,OR]
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} "ia_archiver" [NC,OR]
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} "id\-search" [NC,OR]
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} "IDBot" [NC,OR]
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} "Indy Library" [NC,OR]
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} "IRLbot" [NC,OR]
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} "ISC Systems iRc Search 2\.1" [NC,OR]
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} "LinksCrawler" [NC,OR]
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} "LinksManager\.com_bot" [NC,OR]
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} "linkwalker" [NC,OR]
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} "lwp\-trivial" [NC,OR]
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} "MFC_Tear_Sample" [NC,OR]
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} "Microsoft URL Control" [NC,OR]
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} "Missigua Locator" [NC,OR]
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} "MJ12bot" [NC,OR]
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} "panscient\.com" [NC,OR]
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} "PECL\:\:HTTP" [NC,OR]
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} "PHPCrawl" [NC,OR]
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} "PleaseCrawl" [NC,OR]
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} "SBIder" [NC,OR]
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} "SearchmetricsBot" [NC,OR]
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} "SeznamBot" [NC,OR]
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} "Snoopy" [NC,OR]
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} "Steeler" [NC,OR]
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} "URI\:\:Fetch" [NC,OR]
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} "urllib" [NC,OR]
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} "Web Sucker" [NC,OR]
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} "webalta" [NC,OR]
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} "WebCollage" [NC,OR]
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} "Wells Search II" [NC,OR]
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} "WEP Search" [NC,OR]
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} "XoviBot" [NC,OR]
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} "YisouSpider" [NC,OR]
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} "zermelo" [NC,OR]
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} "ZyBorg" [NC,OR]
    # End Abuse Agent Blocking
    # Start Abuse HTTP Referrer Blocking
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} "^https?://(?:[^/]+\.)?semalt\.com" [NC,OR]
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} "^https?://(?:[^/]+\.)?kambasoft\.com" [NC,OR]
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} "^https?://(?:[^/]+\.)?savetubevideo\.com" [NC]
    # End Abuse HTTP Referrer Blocking
    RewriteRule ^.* - [F,L]
    # End HackRepair.com Blacklist, http://pastebin.com/u/hackrepair

    # Enable the hide backend feature - Security > Settings > Hide Login Area > Hide Backend
    RewriteRule ^(/sagekey/)?dashboard-access/?$ /sagekey/wp-login.php [QSA,L]

    # Protect System Files - Security > Settings > System Tweaks > System Files
    <files .htaccess>
        <IfModule mod_authz_core.c>
            Require all denied
        </IfModule>
        <IfModule !mod_authz_core.c>
            Order allow,deny
            Deny from all
        </IfModule>
    </files>
    <files readme.html>
        <IfModule mod_authz_core.c>
            Require all denied
        </IfModule>
        <IfModule !mod_authz_core.c>
            Order allow,deny
            Deny from all
        </IfModule>
    </files>
    <files readme.txt>
        <IfModule mod_authz_core.c>
            Require all denied
        </IfModule>
        <IfModule !mod_authz_core.c>
            Order allow,deny
            Deny from all
        </IfModule>
    </files>
    <files install.php>
        <IfModule mod_authz_core.c>
            Require all denied
        </IfModule>
        <IfModule !mod_authz_core.c>
            Order allow,deny
            Deny from all
        </IfModule>
    </files>
    <files wp-config.php>
        <IfModule mod_authz_core.c>
            Require all denied
        </IfModule>
        <IfModule !mod_authz_core.c>
            Order allow,deny
            Deny from all
        </IfModule>
    </files>

    # Disable Directory Browsing - Security > Settings > System Tweaks > Directory Browsing
    Options -Indexes

    <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
        RewriteEngine On

        # Protect System Files - Security > Settings > System Tweaks > System Files
        RewriteRule ^wp-admin/includes/ - [F]
        RewriteRule !^wp-includes/ - [S=3]
        RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !^(.*)wp-includes/ms-files.php
        RewriteRule ^wp-includes/[^/]+\.php$ - [F]
        RewriteRule ^wp-includes/js/tinymce/langs/.+\.php - [F]
        RewriteRule ^wp-includes/theme-compat/ - [F]

        # Disable PHP in Uploads - Security > Settings > System Tweaks > Uploads
        RewriteRule ^backend\-files/uploads/.*\.(?:php[1-6]?|pht|phtml?)$ - [NC,F]

        # Filter Request Methods - Security > Settings > System Tweaks > Request Methods
        RewriteCond %{REQUEST_METHOD} ^(TRACE|DELETE|TRACK) [NC]
        RewriteRule ^.* - [F]

        # Filter Suspicious Query Strings in the URL - Security > Settings > System Tweaks > Suspicious Query Strings
        RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} \.\.\/ [NC,OR]
        RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^.*\.(bash|git|hg|log|svn|swp|cvs) [NC,OR]
        RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} etc/passwd [NC,OR]
        RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} boot\.ini [NC,OR]
        RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ftp\:  [NC,OR]
        RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} http\:  [NC,OR]
        RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} https\:  [NC,OR]
        RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (\<|%3C).*script.*(\>|%3E) [NC,OR]
        RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} mosConfig_[a-zA-Z_]{1,21}(=|%3D) [NC,OR]
        RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} base64_encode.*\(.*\) [NC,OR]
        RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^.*(%24&x).* [NC,OR]
        RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^.*(127\.0).* [NC,OR]
        RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^.*(globals|encode|localhost|loopback).* [NC,OR]
        RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^.*(request|concat|insert|union|declare).* [NC]
        RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} !^loggedout=true
        RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} !^action=jetpack-sso
        RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} !^action=rp
        RewriteCond %{HTTP_COOKIE} !^.*wordpress_logged_in_.*$
        RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^http://maps\.googleapis\.com(.*)$
        RewriteRule ^.* - [F]

        # Filter Non-English Characters - Security > Settings > System Tweaks > Non-English Characters
        RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^.*(%0|%A|%B|%C|%D|%E|%F).* [NC]
        RewriteRule ^.* - [F]

        # Reduce Comment Spam - Security > Settings > System Tweaks > Comment Spam
        RewriteCond %{REQUEST_METHOD} POST
        RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} /wp-comments-post\.php$
        RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^$ [OR]
        RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^https?://(([^/]+\.)?rcboa\.com|jetpack\.wordpress\.com/jetpack-comment)(/|$) [NC]
        RewriteRule ^.* - [F]
    </IfModule>
# END iThemes Security - Do not modify or remove this line

# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php
</IfModule>

# END WordPress
```

Most of it's generated by my iTheme Security plugin.

Comment: Doesn't sound like the plugins you've tried support Multisite. Please give some examples of redirects you're trying to setup. Did you change host providers?

Comment: Can you please [edit your question](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/posts/243291/edit) to include the content of your `.htaccess` file?

Comment: @cowgill I never updated hosting providers. I've simply installed "301 Redirects" wordpress plugin and started to point an old domain link to a new one and saved. However when I clear my cache (or open up the site in a new incognito browser) it doesn't redirect the link I'm stating it to redirect.

Comment: @patJ I have done that now

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you're using the right `.htaccess` rules for Multisite.

Generally, these days, they should look like this:

### Subfolder

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]

# add a trailing slash to /wp-admin
RewriteRule ^([_0-9a-zA-Z-]+/)?wp-admin$ $1wp-admin/ [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^ - [L]
RewriteRule ^([_0-9a-zA-Z-]+/)?(wp-(content|admin|includes).*) $2 [L]
RewriteRule ^([_0-9a-zA-Z-]+/)?(.*\.php)$ $2 [L]
RewriteRule . index.php [L]
```

### Subdomain

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]

# add a trailing slash to /wp-admin
RewriteRule ^wp-admin$ wp-admin/ [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^ - [L]
RewriteRule ^(wp-(content|admin|includes).*) $1 [L]
RewriteRule ^(.*\.php)$ $1 [L]
RewriteRule . index.php [L]
```

For more on WordPress and `.htaccess` files, check the [`.htaccess` page on the Codex](https://codex.wordpress.org/htaccess/).

Comment: Thanks for this. By simply adding the subdomain one (as that's what I believe I need) my redirects stated in my plugin will work or should I manually add them to the htaccess file under that code? I'd prefer to do it without a plugin but every time I've tried it never works.

Comment: Do your sites follow the structure site1.example.com, site2.example.com, etc? If so, you're using Subdomain Multisite. If they follow the pattern example.com/site1, example.com/site2, etc, then you're using Subfolder. In either case, you would put the relevant rules in your `.htaccess` file between the `#BEGIN WordPress` and `#END WordPress` lines, replacing the rules that are currently there.

Comment: I completely forgot about this and I've been away fro 2 or so weeks. I've finally put the subdomain rule in my .htaccess file between the #BEGIN WordPress and #END WordPress lines but nothing happened and uploaded it. Does it take time? I made sure my Eggplant 301 Redirects plugin was activated and my old URL's are still going to 404 pages and not my new URL's. Any further help with this is appreciated Pat.